# Custom TextView with horizontal scroll but without focus

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need a single line Text view, without borders where I can enter the text from my custom buttons. I do not want to open the soft keyboard, so want this to be non-focusable. 
It's just as I enter the text through my custom input buttons and that should appear in the Text view along with the cursor at the end of the text.

I tried using TextView but it does not scroll horizontally as I enter the long text. I want this to scroll to the end of the text. If there is longer text, I should be able to scroll manually to view the same.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_margin="3sp"
    android:text="@string/empty"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:id="@+id/gossipTextView"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
    android:layout_gravity="start|top"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the focus from the texView you have to add the following line of code in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` for that specific Activity in which the textView is included.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:label="Registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
```

In order to make single line scrollable text add 2 lines in your

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```